# How do I link to external images on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, media-images

I have an external **dynamic image server**. I would like to link directly to these **external images** and not upload to **Magento's media library**.  I cannot seem to find any setting and/or **extension**.

It appears this may be impossible because there is no option to disable Magento's **image cache** service.

Anyone know how to do this?  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hosting Magento Images on AWS instance](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154797/hosting-magento-images-on-aws-instance)

Comment: Change the media url by logging in to the admin panel and going to Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Base URLs > Base URL for User Media Files and set it to your exrernal image server's base URL

Comment: I tried this.  But it still requires me to upload an image to Magento, I can't just type in a file name... and when it tries to load the external image... it adds all these sub-directories after the base url.  The image is located at the base url, not under all these sub-directories.    Ex..  BASE_URL/catalog/product/cache/f073062f50e48eb0f0998593e568d857/t/s/IMAGE.jpg